# Two coding for same purpose but giving different result

Tags: r

The following two chunk of codes do the same work, but giving different result. It takes  one/two minutes to run the codes:

```
# chunk 1:
n <- 10000000
set.seed(1)
a <- rbinom(n, 1, .5)
b1 <- (a==0) * rexp(n, 1/182.5)
b2 <- (a==1) * rexp(n, 1/365)
e <- (a==1) * rbinom(n, 1, .5)
b3 <- (e==1) * rexp(n, 1/365)
g <- (1-a)*b1 + a*(b2+b3)
p <- length(g[g>150])/length(g)
p

# chunk 2:
n <- 10000000
set.seed(1)
a <- rbinom(n, 1, .5)
b1 <-  rexp(n, 1/182.5)
b2 <-  rexp(n, 1/365)
e <-  rbinom(n, 1, .5)
b3 <-  rexp(n, 1/365)
g <- (1-a)*b1 + a*(b2+b3)
p <- length(g[g>150])/length(g)
p
```

These 2 chunk are same because, for `a` equals to one, the part `(1-a)*b1` in `g` will be disappeared,  it doesn't matter whether `b1` equals to zero or any other value.

Similarly, without `a` being 1, the part `a*(b2+b3)` in `g` will be disappeared. So, it doesn't matter whether an element of `b2` being zero or another value if corresponding element of `a` is zero.

But why does the 2 chunk differ in result?

Comment: What about set.seed()? If you generate random distribution it should be different unless you define a seed.

Comment: @AleksandrVoitov since the `n` is big enough, it will give similar result for 2 decimal place (always I found so). Still I have edited. Thanks.

Comment: @Leaf  IMHO chunk1 calculates another `b1` than chunk2. depending on the values of the elements of `a`. For `a[i]`==0 the same `b1[i]` is calculated, but for `a[i]` ==1 the first chunk calculates `b1[i]` ==0.

Comment: You say that "a equals to one", but that does not seem to be true.  Run _only_ the first three lines of chunk 1, then run `table(a)`.

Comment: @G5W I am not saying all elements of  `a` is equal to one. I meant those elements of `a` for which it is one.

Comment: I see.  I misunderstood what you were asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `(a==0)` and `(a==1)` syntax in chunk 1 looks like it leads to the same numerical result as in chunk 2, but they cause the command `g[g>150]` to slice `g` differently in chunk 1 than it is being sliced in chunk 2.

In chunk 1, `(a==0) * rexp(n, 1/182.5)` ensures that all unwanted indices will be set to zero. In chunk 2, there are still values at those indices, and some of those values could cause `g` to be greater than 150. So,  `length(g[g>150])` is a bigger number for chunk 2, and thus you get a different answer.